# How to deploy cloud application that graphs two companies net profit

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, visualization, wolfram-cloud

What I want to do is to deploy a cloud application that would compare two stocks and (for bonus if it is possible) to also compare the net profit of two companies on a graph.

I tried:

```
MakeGraph[stock_] := 
 Graphics[DateListLogPlot[{FinancialData[
     Entity["Financial", "NASDAQ:NVDA"], "Jan. 1, 2010"], 
    FinancialData[stock, "Jan. 1, 2010"] }, 
   PlotLegends ->  {"Nvidia", stock}, PlotRange -> {0, 700}]]

ob = 
 FormPage["stock" -> "AdministrativeDivision", 
  NarisiGraf["stock"] &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Comparison of two stocks",
    "Description" -> 
     "Input the name of the company to compare it to Nvidia stock", 
    "SubmitLabel" -> "Submit"|>]

CloudDeploy[ob, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

An error occurs when I want it to work: "No administrative division interpretation found. Try again.

"

Does anybody know how to do this the correct way or fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you want the interpreter to parse the name of your stock as "AdministrativeDivision". You should change this to "Financial".

Secondly, you have forgotten to translate `NarisiGraf` to `MakeGraph`.

Thirdly, you cannot use `Entity` in `PlotLegends`. You should obtain its name with `EntityValue`.

Fourthly, the input value in `FormPage` should be used as `#stock` and not `"stock"`.

```
MakeGraph[stock_] := 
 Graphics[DateListLogPlot[{FinancialData[
     Entity["Financial", "NASDAQ:NVDA"], "Jan. 1, 2012"], 
    FinancialData[stock, "Jan. 1, 2012"]}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"Nvidia", EntityValue[stock, "Name"]}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 700}]]

ob = FormPage["stock" -> "Financial", MakeGraph[#stock] &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Comparison of two stocks", 
    "Description" -> 
     "Input the name of the company to compare it to Nvidia stock", 
    "SubmitLabel" -> "Submit"|>]
```

[image: FormPage]

Note that I have changed the date to go from 2012 because I get `$Aborted` otherwise.

Comment: Do you maybe know how to display net profit with comparison to Nvidia company?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "net profit". Do you mean profit of the companies? Then you might find appropriate data with [Company Entity](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Company.html).